# How to set minimum character length for a multi-line text variable in a catalog item

Tags: servicenow

Can anybody tell me how I set the minimum character length to 50 characters in a multi-line variable in a catalog item?

The variable itself is already mandatory but I don't want people to write just "because I want it" or other pointless answers down.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svKTv.png)

This is the perfect example for what I want in ServiceNow.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

1. Add a More information box saying minimum 50 characters
2. Write an onChange script to check the input length (triggers when focus is removed)

```
if (newValue.length < 50){
  g_form.showFieldMsg("field_name_here", "Minimum entry is 50 characters. Please wax poetic!",'error');
}
```

3. Write on onSubmit script to do the same, returning "false" when the char count is <50